# Compute infimum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I want to compute the following infimum:
$$
    \inf\limits_{x_1,\ldots,x_n \geqslant 0}  \dfrac{x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n}{(a_1 x_1^\alpha + \ldots + a_n x_n^\alpha)^{\frac 1 \alpha}}
$$
where $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n) >0$ and $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)>0$, $\alpha \leqslant 1$, $\alpha \neq 0$. What is the easiest way to do this? The straightforward way is to compute partial derivatives and receive a system on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. But this approach yields a huge system of equations.

Lets denote $\beta:$ $\frac 1 \alpha + \frac 1 \beta = 1$, $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, where $b_i = a_i^{-\frac \beta \alpha}$, $i=\overline{1,n}$. Then by solving optimization problem $x \cdot y \to \mathrm{extr}$ on the set $a_1 x_1^\alpha+\ldots + a_n x_n^\alpha = 1$ we obtain a function
$$
   (b_1 y_1^\beta + \ldots + b_n y_n^\beta)^{\frac 1 \beta}.
$$
Will this function be a minimum? Interesting consequence then is the inverse Holder inequality:
$$
    x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n \geqslant (x_1^\alpha+\ldots+x_n^\alpha)^{\frac 1 \alpha} (y_1^\beta + \ldots + y_n^\beta)^{\frac 1 \beta}, \; \frac 1 \alpha + \frac 1 \beta = 1.
$$

Comment: Have you tried to find the minimum under the constraint $\sum_{j=1}^na_jx_j^\alpha=1$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo yes, I've obtained $$
 \left( b_1 y_1^\beta + \ldots + b_n y_n^\beta \right)^{\frac{1}{\beta}},
$$ where $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} = 1$ and $b_i = a_i^{-\frac\beta\alpha}$. But what argument can be used to say that it is minimum and not maximum?

Comment: If $0<\alpha \leq 1$, you get $\beta\leq 0$. In particular, $\beta=0$ for $\alpha=1$. I think this needs to be treated separately.

Comment: Also, the [reverse Holder inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Reverse_H.C3.B6lder_inequality) can simply be deduced from the Holder inequality. That's for the case $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: @julien 1. for $\alpha = 1$ we get $\beta = -\infty$, as the limit it means the function $$ \min \left( c_1 y_1, \ldots, c_n y_n \right),$$ where $c_k$ can be expressed via $b_k$. 2. Of course it can, it's just one another meaning of Holder inequality as a Young inequality for logarithmic Fenhel transform (Young transform): $f(x) f^\times (y) \leqslant \langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: Right, $\beta=-\infty$. I just thought it was worth mentioning that this inequality could be deduced from Holder, without much effort. And actually, it also covers the case $\alpha<0$ since then $0<\beta<1$ and we can exchange them. Didn't you ask for the easiest way to do that?

Comment: @julien yes, I've asked about the easiest way to find this infimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalently, you look for the maximum of $\sum a_j x_j^\alpha$ on the simplex $\sum x_jy_j=1$, $x_j\ge 0$. By compactness, the maximum is attained somewhere. Can it be on a boundary point, where some $x_j$ vanishes? No, because at such point the partial derivative with respect to $x_j$ is infinite, allowing us to increase the function by a little perturbation. Precisely, pick $k$ such that $x_k>0$ and consider the competitor with $x_j$ and $x_k$ replaced with $\epsilon $ and $x_k-(y_j/y_k)\epsilon$, respectively. The derivative of $\sum a_j x_j^\alpha$ with respect to $\epsilon $ is $$a_j \alpha\, \epsilon^{\alpha-1} - O(1)$$ which is posiive for all small $\epsilon$. So, there is no local maximum at a boundary point.

Therefore, the maximum is attained is a stationary point in the interior of the simplex, which you already found.

Comment: I want to add that for $\alpha<0$ our function is defined for $x>0$. But yes, for $\alpha<0$ it become huge when some $x_i \to +0$.